# Get coordinates for Entity from Google AI JSON

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am using Document AI for [reading invoices](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-invoices) by calling the endpoint and then parsing the response JSON to get entities information.

One example of entity JSON data:

[image]

Do you know how to get the coordinate for each entity?

Thanks a lot and any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends which language you're using. If you're using JavaScript, you can directly manipulate a JSON object like such `const coordinates = objectName.textAnchor.textSegments[0]; const start = coordinates.startIndex; const end = coordinates.endIndex`

Comment: @JKleinne hey thanks for your response. but the startIndex and endIndex have nothing to do with coordinates of this entity. Instead, they refer to the start and end positions/indexes of the entity value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounding boxes of [`Entities`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#entity) (or any layout elements in Document AI) in the [`pageAnchor`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#Entity.FIELDS.page_anchor) field.

The [handle the processing response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#basic_text:%7E:text=Document%20AI%20is%20able%20to%20detect%20some%20elements%20in%20the%20page%2C%20such%20as%20the%20paragraphs%20and%20lines.%20Each%20element%20has%20a%20corresponding%20layout%20that%20describes%20its%20position%20and%20text.) page in the documentation has information and illustrations about the structure of the output [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) structure.